# Maintain Web APIs consistency in teams

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Please feel free for editing the caption of this question.

I was part of a team which develops web applications by using AngularJS and Web APIs. We developed Web APIs for each page and grab data by Angular.
after a while, We realized the most of web APIs are sames, because we could not realized which Web APIs already exists. In some cases, we have same APIs but different routes. 
For example, in ShowOrderDetail.html we need to show the user's profile info. A developer implements a Web API to retrieve data from UserProfile ( only 3 fields). However, in other page another developer implements another API to retrieve 5 fields.

I would like to know if you have any other experiences in designing these kind of systems and how handle this issue. Is there other techniques or tools instead of managerial aspects (like setting name convention)?

Comment: Are you saying that you created a completely separate web service for each page in your site?

Comment: yes, exactly. each developer is full stack web developer. their responsibilities are designing SQL Table, implements Web APIs and develop front-end by HTML, Javascript and AngularJS

Comment: It seems your project has architectural and design problems, it's not the way to go. You should have started with designing the **API** and then implementing your client side app around that designed server side API.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to create a lot of separate services for the same project, and it's certainly excessive to create a completely separate Web API for every single individual page in the web site. This'll inevitably lead to a lot of redundancy and wasted effort regardless of other means you're using to organize your code (tools, naming conventions, etc.).

I'd suggest reorganizing your services in terms of the operations you're performing regularly, *not* in terms of one service per page. You can create separate controllers to organize your service into different types of operations (in fact, I'd recommend this - [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) has a good description of different ways of organizing code) but again this should be organized in terms of reusable operations, *not* in terms of individual pages.